# Is their any way to change input date format in html5

Tags: html, date

It is displaying in mm/dd/yyyy, in other computer chrome beta version it is giving dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your computer's culture settings. Go to Control Panel -> Region and Languge option and see whether they are same.

Try these solutions in the SO posts as well

[How to make <input type="date"> display the date in localized format in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721647/how-can-i-make-input-type-date-format-for-localized-culture-in-chrome)

[HTML-5 date field shows as "mm/dd/yyyy" in Chrome, even when valid date is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647290/html-5-date-field-shows-as-mm-dd-yyyy-in-chrome-even-when-valid-date-is-set)